# Does Visual Studio 2022 prevent more than one developer accessing the same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, locking, visual-studio-2022

For years I have been using VS solo. Now we have added a member to the "team." With this new arrangement, I want to make sure we are not both working on the same code at the same time. Will VS 2022 prevent both of us from opening or making changes to a solution or file if it is open in the other's environment?

This may be a ridiculous question, but as I said, this is a new arrangement for me. I've searched the net for this specific issue and can't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working on the same machine? Do you know Version Control systems like Git?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer - We don't even work in the same state. And I never got into a Git type of setup. I've been coding in some form or another for 40 years, so Git is a new concept which I never felt like I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer It may be relevant to add that my development machine is in the office where the other team member is, and I access it by RDP. And all of the files are on that machine, not on a server or on my local machine.

Comment: The first company I worked at used ZIP files between developers as "source control". I would recommend Git as suggested by @MarkusMeyer. It seems daunting at first, but with just two developers (or at least a small team), it will be worth it even though it seems it might not. I would try an account at [GitHub](https://github.com). It can't hurt to try it out, and will probably prevent headaches that would be associated with sharing the same files between two people.

Comment: @BillNorman Worth pointing out that you’ll be gaining much more than being able to work together by using Git.  You’ll also get a rigorous history of why changes were made.  A good instant backup of your source.  The ability to make changes and easily undo them to a known point.  The ability to review each other’s work before it enters the main branch.  Also, this is how 99.9% of devs typically work these days so it’s a transferable skill.